# Hats everywhere but the profile picture on the Winter Bash homepage doesn't wear a hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Hats, hats, and hats everywhere but why doesn't the profile picture on the Winter Bash homepage wear a hat?

Comment: most likely because it was never implemented, if you look at your browser's console, you see a complete different built compared to a regular SE page